# Failed to install PostgreSQL 8.3, failed to run initdb:1?

Tags: postgresql, installation

I am reinstalling PostgreSQL using pgInstaller postgresql-8.3.16-1. An Error occurs in the last step of the install process:

> Failed to run initdb:1!

`\tmp\initdb.log` shows this message:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or
>   use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

The message is quite simple but I can't locate the root cause of the install failure.

Any one knows what's the reason?

Comment: Better fit for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already have a database cluster installed in the location where your Posgres8.3 install is trying to init a new one.  You can't really mix and match versions like that.

If possible, install the old version you had when you created the existing database.  Then use [pg_dumpall](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) to create a `.SQL` dump of all of your data.  You can then move or delete the old database (usually at `/var/lib/pgsql`) and install the new version.  finally, apply the database dump to get the old data back.

For more details on this, read the [Upgrading a PostgreSQL cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html) manual page.

If you are installing the same version, there's no need to upgrade the cluster, you can probably safely ignore errors about `initdb`, so long as everything runs Ok.